# Как найти проекцию точки на окружность?

Tags: c++, геометрия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что означает *"проекция точки на окружность по углу отрезка от точки к центру"* и как это можно найти?

Comment: квадрат расстояния `dx * dx + dy * dy`; угол до точки `atan2(dy, dx)`

Comment: Сортировать нужно по углу. Бонусные очки, если придумаете, как это сделать без тригонометрических функций вроде `atan2` (по косинусу/синусу, взятым из скалярного/векторного произведений).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что означает проекция точки на окружность

Проведите луч из центра окружности через данную точку. Пересечение луча с окружностью - это проекция точки на окружность.

> отсортированы ... по углу отрезка от точки к центру

Проекции N точек на окружность нужно упорядочить - как если бы Вы шли по окружности все время в одну сторону и встречали эти проекции одну за другой.